# Remove clicked appended item with jQuery

Tags: jquery

My + button duplicates the  element and - button removes last appended element.

```
$('#btnNewMobilePhone').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.phonemobile').append(' <div class="form-group"><label for="email" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cep Telefonu</label><div class="col-sm-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone_mobile[]"  placeholder="Mobile Phone"></div><div class="col-sm-2"> <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary btnRemMobilePhone"> <i class="entypo-plus"> -</i> </a> </div></div>');
});
$('.phonemobile').on('click', '.btnRemMobilePhone', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.phonemobile .form-group:last').remove();
});
```

This code removes last appended element. But I want to remove the clicked element insted of last element. Is it possible? I couldn't find the solution.

Is there a way using something like

```
.form-group:this
```

Comment: Where's a [mcve]? This looks totally unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use context(`this`) of clicked element to traverse to closest parent `form-group` element and then remove it:

```
$('.phonemobile').on('click', '.btnRemMobilePhone', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last clicked element, you should use:

`$('.phonemobile .form-group').find(e.currentTarget).remove();`

e.currentTarget will you the element which were clicked inside a form-group and remove them. If you would like to remove only those elements which were clicked and outside form group, you should use `$(e.currentTarget).remove();`